# Dead presidents

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I need to find out the probability that at least 2 of the presidents of the United States have died on the same day of the year.

I'm tempted to put 100% since it has actually happened (during the same year even!), but I am sure that is not the correct answer.

I have a suspicion that the math for this would be the same as the birthday problem, and the answer would be the same as the formula for that plugging in for 38 people.

Is this correct?

Comment: Think about finding the probability that two *haven't* died on the same day.

Comment: Probability is a man-made concept. It has nothing to do with the real world. Keeping that in mind may save you from trying to derive conclusion like the one you said, and from taking too seriously all headlines in the news that begin "A study from the University ... has shown that ... "

Comment: Ah, the conundrum of "Real world probability" vs. "Theoretical question".

Comment: I don't understand; you do have the full data for presidents and their dates of death. Then just compute the ratio.

Comment: @user99680 There is no ratio involved :). You have the historical data, just check and conclude that it is 100%.

Comment: Face palm!  ↑  ↑  ↑

Comment: @gt6989b: you're right; I misread as will die on the same date.

Comment: I think the only reasonable answer to this question is that it's not well posed. If you're supposed to pretend you don't know the death dates, shouldn't you also pretend that you don't know how many are still alive? So the person who posed it should specify precisely what information you have as prior knowledge.

Comment: 100% is definitely the correct answer for the reason that you mentioned.  Granted some people might not _like_ the answer, but you shouldn't let anyone you that it isn't the _correct_ answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly say: this is just the [Birthday Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirthdayProblem.html) but with deaths instead of births.